# Filipino wife going to Europe to live

Tags: schengen, spain, eu-spouses, philippine-citizens

I'm an Irish citizen currently living in Ireland. However I plan to relocate to Spain. Next year I plan to marry my Filipino girlfriend and we are going to live together permanently in Spain. I spoke to the Spanish Embassy here in Dublin and they say she will have no problem getting a Schengen visa for Spain as she'll be the wife of an EU citizen. However I keep reading about off loads at Manila airport. If she has a valid Schengen visa, valid passport and we travel to Spain together is that enough for her to pass Immigration. Or are there other requirements?